# Cant understand what happens when i run this code

Tags: c, function, recursion

I can't understand why the result of effe(10) procedure is 110. (Thats a code taken from an exercise)

I tried to write down what is happening in the code, but there are too many recursions and i can't understand what is happening.

```
int effe(int);
int gi(int);

int main(){
    int test = effe(10);
    printf("%d\n", test); //this prints 110
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

int effe(int a){
    if(a < 2)
    return a * 2;
    else
    return (gi(a - 1) + gi(a - 2));
}

int gi(int a){
    if (a < 2)
    return effe(a);
    else
    return (effe(a - 1) + effe(a - 2));
}
```

Comment: There's a total of 133 calls of `effe` and 88 calls of `gi`. Without any comments (or good variable/function names) it's hard to say what this program is supposed to calculate.

Comment: I would toss a couple `printf`s in there.  `printf("In gi, a = %d", a);`

Comment: I know but thats not a " real program" thats an exersice taken from a kind of computer technology competition that my school organised. The exercise asks you to find the number returned after calling the effe(10) function. I think that maybe there is a short way to understand it.... i don't know....

Comment: @SteveSummit Happy to hear this. I'm also very bad at these puzzles: my brain just crashes when i see these things

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To some extent, this is variation of Fibonacci.

Calculate the values starting with efff(0), gi(0), and calculate efff(1), gi(1),efff(2), gi(2), until you reach efff(10), gi(10)

```
a    efff(a)    gi(a)
0    0           0
1    2           2
2    2=2+0       2=2+0
3    4=2+2       4=2+2
4    6=2+4       6=2+4
5    10=4+6      10=4+6
6    16=6+10     16=6+10
7    26          26
8    42          42
9    68          68
10   110         110
```

Note that each item is 2 times the Fibonacci value (1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55).